# Regex Match Commas Outside Quotes - XML Schema Variant

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

At first glance, this looks like a common question: I want to match on commas, but exclude commas that are in between a pair of "double quotes". However, what makes this challenging is that I need to do this with the XML Schema flavor of regex ([W3C Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/)).

All the solutions I could find for this involved a lookahead, which is not a feature in this flavor of regex. The closest I got was this:

```
(?:"[^"]*")|(,)
```

This avoids matching a comma inside quotes by instead matching the quotes as well as any text inside it as a separate group. One suggestion I ran into went like this:

```
(?:"[^"]*")(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(,)
```

This would work perfectly, but again, (*SKIP) and (*FAIL) are not available in this variant of regex.

[Here is a sample.](https://regex101.com/r/4GPPy5/2)

```
Foo,Bar,"TEST, QUOTES",,Blah
```

This test string should have 4 matches - each comma, excluding the one in the middle between the quotes. It should match on only the comma, not the text between them.

I'm at a loss, internet. Is this even possible with the limited tools at my disposal? My only other alternative would be much messier and probably slower if I can't get this regex to work.

Comment: Can you provide us with sample strings and their expected output?

Comment: Can you provide an example on https://regex101.com/ and is it just the comma you need to match?

Comment: When you say you want to "match on commas", what exactly do you mean? If you're using XSD regex then presumably you are validating strings: what strings for this type are valid, and what strings are invalid?

Comment: @MichaelKay I am using a file format definition tool that only supports xml style regex. You can specify delimiters with a regex pattern, so by matching on commas I can split the fields much like you would when parsing a CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the limited ability of XML regex you won't be able to solve this problem, it's the wrong tool. I suggest using an XML parser do manipulate content as needed instead.

The XML regex flavor is mostly used for validation and Unicode properties... but not for a complex task like yours.

> XML Schema regular expressions support the [following](https://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html):
>
> - Character classes, including shorthands, ranges and negated classes.
> - Character class subtraction.
> - The dot, which matches any character except line breaks.
> - Alternation and groups.  Greedy quantifiers `?`, `*`, `+` and `{n,m}`
> - Unicode properties and blocks

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought that might be the case. The software that I am using is supposed to let me define a file format so I can do transformations against the file, so the regex is actually to split fields by a delimiter. XML is the back-bone of the software, so even though I am parsing a CSV it requires XML style regex.

I suppose I will just have to write a separate program to manipulate the file first before I toss it in to the program for further manipulation.